How to get custom trained Bert tokenizer not to split certain characters
I am training my own tokenizer based on bert-based-cased. The problem I have is that in my data (dead language), there are tokens that begin with = and this should not be split off from the rest of the token. How do I achieve that?
Thanks for your help!
